# what's the easy way to make a simple window and catch key presses in Rust?

Tags: rust, accessibility, game-engine, screen-readers

I am a blind Rust learner and i'm trying to make a simple audiogame engine for blind people but in rust.
Now I'm trying to make a simple window. A game for blind uses only audio and keyboard, so i have a question.
I'm trying to create an empty window and catch key presses to be able to make a self voiced user interface and game interaction using keyboard only, without mouce. what's the best solution for that?

I tryed to use winit and winit input helper, but maybe there is a better way to do that?

```
use winit::event::VirtualKeyCode;
use winit::event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop};
use winit::window::WindowBuilder;
use winit_input_helper::WinitInputHelper;

pub fn show_window() {
    let mut input = WinitInputHelper::new();
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let _window = WindowBuilder::new().build(&event_loop).unwrap();

    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        // Pass every event to the WindowInputHelper.
        // It will return true when the last event has been processed and it is time to run your application logic.
        if input.update(&event) {
            // query keypresses this update
            if input.key_pressed_os(VirtualKeyCode::A) {
                println!("The 'A' key was pressed on the keyboard (OS repeating)");
            }

            if input.key_pressed(VirtualKeyCode::A) {
                println!("The 'A' key was pressed on the keyboard");
            }

            if input.key_released(VirtualKeyCode::Q) || input.quit() {
                *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey! Stackoverflow is a community about helping with specific programming questions and not about giving recommendations like your question asks for, it is offtopic.
You should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask questions to specific problems if there are any.

Comment: than where to ask such questions? i remember that i saw that kind of questions on StackOverflow so i thaught this is ok

Comment: The [Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) allows much more open-ended discussions and is probably the best place to ask this kind of question.